# Postgres.App installation

Tags: macos, postgresql, terminal

this is probably a total newbie question but try as I might, I cannot seem to get my terminal to recognize the psql command.  So far, I have tried the following:

1. Added PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH" to my .profile file, saved, and reopened terminal.  No luck. (Path that is given in the Postgres.App installation instructions on their site.)
2. Added PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH" to my .bash_profile file, saved, and reopened terminal.  No luck.  (Tried another file to be sure.)
3. Added export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH" to my .profile file, saved, and reopened terminal.  No luck.  (Recommended in another question asked here on Stack.)
4. Same deal as previous but in .bash_profile.  No luck.
5. Same deal but with /Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.3 in both .profile and .bash_profile.  No luck. (Data directory given in the app preferences, running out of ideas.)

What am I missing?  This shouldn't be this hard.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you run `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql` what happens?

Comment: It works when I run it.

Comment: Output of `echo $PATH` ? What OS/X version are you on? What's the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: echo $path - **/Users/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/my_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/my_user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/my_user/.rvm/bin**

Comment: OSX Mavericks and echo $SHELL - **/bin/bash**

Comment: You know that `$PATH` and `$path` are different right (`$path` isn't meaningful for anything). Anyway, it's clear that your `.bash_profile` entry isn't having any effect; can you show the output of `bash -x -l; echo $PATH` (on pastebin.com or something) ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I know much but I will say that I mistyped the $path. I meant and have been using $PATH as that is what I'd seen in all the resources.  Here is a pastebin of the output you requested: http://pastebin.com/JtdHBrpJ  And thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Well, your statements aren't actually being executed. At a guess you're editing the wrong user's `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it never ceases to amaze me how much is knowledge is assumed by the courses, programs, and even installation instructions dealing with unix based systems.  Like I thought, it was a silly issue.

I've heard repeatedly and from multiple sources that to make sure changes are applied, restart your terminal.  Well, in this case, that is not enough.  If you find yourself in the same situation, you must either restart your computer or (and much more simply) issue the following command in terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

While a silly little issue, ignorance doesn't care and your stuff won't work until eradicate said ignorance.  The good thing is that with each new hard won gem of knowledge, that's one more thing I won't forget anytime soon and insight into how to better diagnose future problems.